# Create list from user input and modify some elements

Tags: python, list

Good day

I am trying to write a that will prompt me to enter five integer numbers and store them in an array. The program should then add 5 to those elements divisible by 5. 
Then I want to display the modified array.

A sample run: 
Enter an integer number: 10 
Enter an integer number: 8 
Enter an integer number: 15 
Enter an integer number: 9 
Enter an integer number: 44 
The modified array is: 
15 8 20 9 44

Code:

```
num=[]
for i in range (5):
      x=int(input(“Enter and integer number: \n”))
      num.insert(i,x)
      d iv=filter((lambda x:x%5==0),num)
print(div)
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far in your question, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far, and change the title of your post to describe the *specific* problem you are having, otherwise your post will be of no use or interest to anyone else.

Comment: I get the numbers in an array list but I am struggling to add 5 to those elements divisible by 5

Comment: Please update the question with your code rather than post in the comments.

Comment: What does your title have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use list comprehension:

```
my_list=[]
for i in range(5):
    n=int(input("Enter and integer number:"))
    my_list.append(n)
print(my_list)

for index, i in enumerate(my_list):
    if i%5==0:
        my_list[index] = i + 5
print (my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_of_south_africa=[int(input("Enter an integer number") for i in range(5)]
array_of_south_africa=[i+(5 if i%5==0 else 0) for i in array]
```

From what is said in your question, this should work. Give more details if your needs are more specifics.